# URL helper for acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code isn't working

```
<p>Tags: <%= @video.tags.map { |t| link_to t.name, tag_path(t)}.join(', ') %></p>
```

Rails complains about `undefined method 'tag_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd0f0260890>:0x007fd0ebce5f68>`

I think tag_path is just not the right url_helper, can anybody explain which one to use here?

My `rake routes`

```
              video_tags GET    /videos/:video_id/tags(.:format)                  tags#index
                     POST   /videos/:video_id/tags(.:format)                  tags#create
       new_video_tag GET    /videos/:video_id/tags/new(.:format)              tags#new
      edit_video_tag GET    /videos/:video_id/tags/:id/edit(.:format)         tags#edit
           video_tag GET    /videos/:video_id/tags/:id(.:format)              tags#show
                     PATCH  /videos/:video_id/tags/:id(.:format)              tags#update
                     PUT    /videos/:video_id/tags/:id(.:format)              tags#update
                     DELETE /videos/:video_id/tags/:id(.:format)              tags#destroy
              videos GET    /videos(.:format)                                 videos#index
                     POST   /videos(.:format)                                 videos#create
           new_video GET    /videos/new(.:format)                             videos#new
          edit_video GET    /videos/:id/edit(.:format)                        videos#edit
               video GET    /videos/:id(.:format)                             videos#show
                     PATCH  /videos/:id(.:format)                             videos#update
                     PUT    /videos/:id(.:format)                             videos#update
                     DELETE /videos/:id(.:format)                             videos#destroy
```

Apart from that, I did not change my routes.rb, which looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  get 'welcome/index'

  root 'welcome#index'

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :videos do
    resources :tags
  end

end
```

Comment: What is in your routes?

Comment: I just updated the post with the routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I got it working this way:

Added resource to routes.rb:

```
  resources :videos do
    resources :tags
  end
```

With the routes set up, I changed my RHTML to look like this:

```
<p>
Tags: 
  <%= raw @video.tags.map {
        |t| link_to t.name, video_tag_path(:video_id => @video.id, :id => t.id)
    }.join(', ') %>
</p>
```

Had to specify the video_id and tag id parameter explicitly.

For tags, you have to generate a controller afterwards.